# Rails Mutually exclusive fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have something like:

```
class Event
  validates :name, :prescence => true
  belongs_to :parent, class => "Event", foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :children, class => "Event"
```

I want to change it so that a name is only required when an event doesn't have a parent.

Answer (score 3):

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new {|event| event.parent.blank? }
```

should work fine. Please read [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for further information.

Comment: You can have an optional :if condition on validates. Read here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

Comment: @Roadmaster Thanks for the link. I've added it to the answer ;)

Comment: broken link. Can you update it? Also is this still the current way to do this?

Comment: If you'd like to read more about conditional validations, this is a [working link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) (the one above is outdated)